# Can fancybox be called on a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I'm unable to call fancybox on an element like this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.comments').fancybox();
```

**Is that not possible? Is it due to it being a class instead of an id?**

I have several rows of items so it's not possible to have ids for all of them.

Any advice? Here is the whole JS code (the show() here works, but fancybox() fails):

```
$(".action").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.comments').show();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that you're actually getting an element back?

Comment: Does `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.comments')` return you the entity you expect?

Comment: Yeah it does. I've tried to just show() it and it works.

Comment: I've added the JS code to the question for more reference.

Comment: have you tried setting the element into a var and calling fancybox on it?
var $target = $(this).closest('.comments');
$target.fancybox();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling it the wrong way; try the following:

```
$('.action').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    target = $(this).closest('.comments').html();
    $.fancybox({
        content: target
        // More Options
    });
    return false;
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It definitely brings up the modal -- but it's blank.

Comment: I guess it`s hidden, so use `content: $(this).closest('.comments').show()`

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.fancybox()` on an element only initializes fancybox. The best way to implement it depends on your HTML, which you didn't post.

But regardless, this solution should work:

```
$(".action").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var jqA = $(a);

    jqA.fancybox({
        content: $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.comments').html()
        // other options go here
    });

    jqA.click();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: NP. I think dSquared's solution might be better if you add `.html()` to the end of line 3 - I didn't realize you could open a modal calling `$.fancybox();` directly

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
$(this).closest('.comments').fancybox();
```

outside click functions.